# How to retrieve an id after details are submitted

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I am having trouble with a major flaw with my database design. Below is my four tables:

**Session Table:**

```
SessionId  SessionName
3           EROEW
```

**Question Table:**

```
QuestionId(PK)  QuestionNo  QuestionContent  SessionId (FK)
11              1           Question1        3    
12              2           Question2        3
13              3           Question3        3
```

**Image_Question:**

```
ImageQuestionId (PK) ImageId (FK) SessionId (Fk)  QuestionNo (FK)
1                    1              3               1
2                    2              3               2
```

**Image:**

```
ImageId (PK)  SessionId (Fk)  QuestionNo (FK)
1              3               1
2              3               2
```

Now as you can see in the `Image_Question` Table, the `QuestionNo` refers to a `QuestionNo` which is non-unique or in other words a non unique field. Now I head this is bad practice.

Now I know you are going to say why not use `QuestionId`. Well the problem is that I can't use `QuestionId` because the images are uploaded to each question before a question is submitted and the only way we can give a question its own `QuestionId` is after the user has submitted the questions.

So what I tried to do was determine which question an uploaded image belongs to by getting the `QuestionNo` from the page as well as the `SessionId`.

Now as I have heard this is a bad way of doing it, I want to change `QuestionNo (FK)` in `Image_Question` to `QuestionId (FK)`. But I am not going to be able to upload files and insert details of the uplaod after questions are submitted to get the `QuestionId`, to me that can't be done.

So my question is that is there a way we can some how store each uploaded image into a temp table, get the question number and sessionid for each image belongs to and then from there be able to find the `QuestionId` and store the `QuestionId` value in the `Image_Question` Table?

Below is my current php code where it inserts the values after image is uploaded:

Be very greatful if somebody can update code below but any answer will be helpful:

```
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;


    $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
    VALUES (?)";

    //Dont pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable
$insert->bind_param("s",$img);

//Assign the variable
$img = 'ImageFiles/'.$_FILES['fileImage']['name'];  //GET THE IMAGE UPLOADED

 $insert->execute();

        $insert->close();


        $lastImageID = $mysqli->insert_id; 

$_SESSION['lastImageID'] = $lastImageID; 
$_SESSION['ImageFile'] = $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]; 


        $sessid =  $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : ''); GET THE NAME OF THE SESSION    

$sessionquery = "SELECT SessionId FROM Session WHERE (SessionName = ?)";  //FIND SESSIONID by finding it's SESSIONNAME


// Bind parameter for statement
$sessionstmt->bind_param("s", $sessid);

// Execute the statement
$sessionstmt->execute();

// This is what matters. With MySQLi you have to bind result fields to
// variables before calling fetch()
$sessionstmt->bind_result($sessionid);

// This populates $sessionid
$sessionstmt->fetch();

    $sessionstmt->close();        

 $imagequestionsql = "INSERT INTO Image_Question (ImageId, SessionId, QuestionNo)  //INSERT DETAILS INTO CURRENT IMAGE_QUESTION TABLE
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)"; 

     if (!$insertimagequestion = $mysqli->prepare($imagequestionsql)) { 
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here 
       echo "Prepare statement err imagequestion"; 
    } 

$qnum = (int)$_POST['numimage']; //QUESTION NUMBER IMAGE IS UPLOADED IN

$insertimagequestion->bind_param("iii",$lastImageID, $sessionid, $qnum); 

    $insertimagequestion->execute(); 

                if ($insertimagequestion->errno) { 
          // Handle query error here 
        } 

        $insertimagequestion->close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest problem is the fact that your schema isn't normalized.  Doing so should help you some.
Here's how I recommend structuring your database:

**Session:**

```
SessionId  SessionName
3          EROEW
```

**Question:**

```
QuestionId(PK)  QuestionContent  SessionId (FK)
11              Question1        3    
12              Question2        3
13              Question3        3
```

**Image:**

```
ImageId (PK)
1           
2
```

**Image_Question:**

```
ImageId (FK) QuestionId (FK) -- (Composite primary key)
1            11
2            12
```

The insert order for the tables should be:

```
Session -> Question -
                     \
                      -- Image_Question
                     /
              Image -
```

You'll be dodging potential update issues, and data conflicts otherwise.